# TSQL Increment Cursor (row_number) used instead

Tags: t-sql, cursor

So I have the following table:

`ID  |   Product_Image` 
`300         |   /300-01.jpg` 
`300          |   /300-02.jpg` 
`301        |   /301.jpg` 
`302          |   /302.jpg`

There could be an unlimited number of images per ID.  I need to increment a position id based on the the number of references, and I am having trouble generating the following output:

`ID | Position | Product Images` 
`300 |  1  | /300-01.jpg` 
`300 |  2  | /300-02.jpg` 
`301 |  1 | /301.jpg`

Currently I am using a cursor but having trouble with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` for that:

```
select  ID
,       row_number() over (partition by ID order by Product_Image) as Position
,       Product_Image
from    YourTable
```

Answer (score 3):

drop the cursor and use the T-SQL ROW_NUMBER with an OVER clause.  here is a reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx